# MongoDB local won't connect when deploying via Heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose, deployment

One of the error logs is this:
**MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017**

dbURI I'm using in my Node.js:

```
const dbURI = process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/the-little-helper';
```

My question is, do I need to use a cloud server (i.e., MongoDB Atlas) to be able to deploy my web application or can I use my local server for storing database?

Note: Heroku is what I'm currently using to deploy, feel free to leave suggestions for other sites similar to heroku.

Also, if the previous statements weren't enough information, here is the log of all the errors:

```
2021-05-24T19:04:50.910961+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-05-24T19:04:54.247315+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-05-24T19:04:54.247332+00:00 app[web.1]: > profile@1.0.0 start /app
2021-05-24T19:04:54.247332+00:00 app[web.1]: > node Node.js
2021-05-24T19:04:54.247333+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-05-24T19:04:54.947931+00:00 app[web.1]: Connection success!
2021-05-24T19:04:54.954409+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
2021-05-24T19:04:54.954411+00:00 app[web.1]: designed for a production environment, as it will leak
2021-05-24T19:04:54.954411+00:00 app[web.1]: memory, and will not scale past a single process.
2021-05-24T19:05:24.952175+00:00 app[web.1]: MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
2021-05-24T19:05:24.952186+00:00 app[web.1]: at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:846:32)
2021-05-24T19:05:24.952186+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:350:10
2021-05-24T19:05:24.952187+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:5
2021-05-24T19:05:24.952187+00:00 app[web.1]: at new Promise (<anonymous>)
2021-05-24T19:05:24.952188+00:00 app[web.1]: at promiseOrCallback (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:30:10)
2021-05-24T19:05:24.952188+00:00 app[web.1]: at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1154:10)
2021-05-24T19:05:24.952189+00:00 app[web.1]: at Mongoose.connect (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:349:20)
2021-05-24T19:05:24.952189+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/Node.js:17:10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you must need cloud base mongodb Cluster like Atlas and add the cloud base mongodb URI to your heroku env variables to run your app without any errors.